# How to test hooks with react router navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm having some problems testing hooks with `renderHook` utility when the hook has some navigation logic. I'm not able to simulate a navigation on the test.

For example lets take this sample hook

```js
export const useNavBar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const isExpandable = useMemo(() => {
    const aPath = matchPath({path: "/a-rute"}, location.pathName);
    const anotherPath = matchPath({path: "/another-rute"}, location.pathName);

    return !aPath && !anotherPath
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return { isExpandable }
}
```

Currently I want to try that when the user navigates to a non-expandable route, it changes. However, it seems it is ignoring `window.history.pushState` in test.

```js
it("changes expandable accessing an invalid route", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(useNavBar, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });    
  expect(result.current.isExpandable).toBeTruthy();
 
  window.history.pushState({}, '', '/a-route');

  expect(result.current.isExpandable).toBeFalsy();
}
```

Calling `window.history.pushState` does not trigger a rerender, so it does not update the value. Also calling `rerender` manually has no effect because `useLocation` does not notice the changes.

So, how can update the location using `renderHook`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `BrowserRouter` isn't aware of any `window.history.pushState`, and likely doesn't work in a Node.js environment anyway. In unit tests we typically use the [`MemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router).

I've not worked with `renderHook` much, but I suspect you could create a wrapper that renders a `HistoryRouter` that is passed a custom `memoryHistory` object (*e.g. a memory router*) that you can then use to effect the navigation action.

Example:

```
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; // <-- v6
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history"; // <-- history@5

const history = createMemoryHistory(); // defaults to `"/"`

const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <Router history={history}>
    {children}
  </Router>
);

it("changes expandable accessing an invalid route", () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(useNavBar, { wrapper: RouterWrapper });    
  expect(result.current.isExpandable).toBeTruthy();
 
  // Navigate to new path
  act(() => {
    history.push("/a-route");
  });

  expect(result.current.isExpandable).toBeFalsy();
}
```

This all assumes you are using `react-router-dom@6`. If you are using the older v5 version, then import the low-level [`Router`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/core/api/Router) and ensure you have `history@4` as a dependency for compatibility.

Comment: The migration guide recommends to remove `history` dependency. But I guess this is a valid exception of the rule. Thanks for the workaround :)